# Looking for manual ways to remove the damaged package

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Ubuntu 16.04 and me are looking for ways to clean up the damaged package, bus errors reported, when dpkg tries to remove the pieces of old kernel. No new packages can be installed:

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic
(Reading database ... 210811 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic (4.4.0-36.55) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-36-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
Bus error (core dumped)
Bus error (core dumped)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return code 135
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic
```

Comment: This looks like the current kernel in 16.04. Why are you trying to remove it? Cheers, Al

Comment: PLease [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/820588/edit) your question with the output of `uname -r`.

Comment: dpkg tries to remove linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic at every attempt to install new packages, fails and is not installing. By purging I was trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best solution and will cost me one day, but I removed all files related to the linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic, changed directory to dpkg

cd /var/lib/dpkg

and removed the description related to the package from the status file, searching with Ctrl-W in nano.

sudo nano status

So far it works...